# Backup a database in WebSitePanel

Tags: sql-server, backup, cpanel, database-backups, remote-backup

I can't create a backup of a database (MS SQL 2005), using WebsitePanel. When I select the database and try to click on the "Backup" button from "Maintenance Tools", the "Backup" button is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically means that your hosting plan does not include the "backup" feature in the database section.